# Read a solution file using Python API of CPLEX

Tags: python, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I have a MIP and I solve the problem within a matheuristic framework, therefore I solve the problem multiple times. However, I want to save certain solutions and read the solutions from those files and not solve the model each time to save me some time. Is there any way I can read a solution file with CPLEX API in Python?

I need to use CPLEX, I have already coded everything in CPLEX API so DOCplex won't work for me.

I tried using read function from CPLEX but it didn't accept .sol files.

I also tried model.read("solution.sav") after saving the solution as an sav file by doing m.solution.write("solution.sav") but it didn't work either. It gives an error saying that the file I am trying to read is not an SAV file.

Comment: Saving and re-reading your solutions from a file is probably slow. Why not just store your solutions in memory?

Comment: I think I'll just store my solutions like you said since CPLEX method didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A solution file is a .mst file and you can rely on read(self, filename)

The example from cplex documentation:

```
import cplex
c = cplex.Cplex()
out = c.set_results_stream(None)
out = c.set_log_stream(None)
c.read("ind.lp")
c.solve()
c.MIP_starts.write("test_all.mst")
c.MIP_starts.read("test_all.mst")
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me either. But thank you.